# Promoting the Workplace SE through community outreach to bloggers

Tags: discussion, blog, site-promotion

There is still interest in hosting a community blog; however, we don't yet have enough content and writers to justify the Wordpress development for an actual Wordpress SE blog.

I still think we could eventually have a blog, but there isn't quite enough interest just yet.  So, here's an alternate proposal.

Some of our community members have blogs or write on topics about the workplace. Since the content on The Workplace is licensed under the [cc-wiki Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), this site is a perfect repository of knowledge for someone wishing to do some research on a specific topic and post it on their own, already existing blog.

Instead of hosting our own blog at this time, does anyone know of popular bloggers we could reach out to who would find our questions and answers interesting material to use as a source of ideas for their own blogs?

If we can help them find ideas for new articles on their own blogs, the Workplace SE benefits from reference and attribution links back to the questions and answers the author uses to compose his or her articles.  The more blogs that contain links to our content, the greater the potential for more visits and conversions from visitor to contributing user.

## **Here's your challenge, if you wish to help out:**

- Find workplace-related blogs on the Internet; specifically, successful blogs or those with potential to be successful.
- Locate an article where the author asks a question of their community.  Look for articles where that question hasn't been meaningfully answered.
- Provide an answer to the question, using a link back to the Workplace SE as a reference supporting the answer you leave in the comments. Remember, the goal isn't to spam these bloggers. Instead, we must add value by contributing meaningful ideas to the discussion.
- Be sure to use the "share" links when sharing questions. This helps you earn the Publicist, Booster, and Announcer badges when new visitors visit The Workplace.

Also, if you know a well-known blogger, ask him or her where he or she gets ideas for what to write about. If the opportunity arises, use the site's [elevator pitch](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq) to briefly describe what the site is about; emphasize the fact that the content is essentially free to use -- with proper attribution -- and will help that blogger with ideas, answers to questions, and more consistent published articles that will keep their users coming back for more, while still directing that traffic to our site.