# Are we ready to graduate?

Tags: discussion, graduation

About 8 months ago we had this question:

[When will The Workplace Graduate?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/when-will-the-workplace-graduate)

One of the things that came out of that was that we needed to grow more and about 3k questions would have us at the mark that we would be self sustaining.  We are almost there.  Our visits per day has been exploding and our core user base is strong.  We have become a great site that is helpful the many in real world situations.

I think its time for us to move to the next step. Are we missing something to graduate?  If so I hope that SE Would let us know.  Otherwise please let us graduate.  In the alternative if the SE powers do not think we are quite there can we get an extra mod or 2 to help handle the volume that we have?

Comment: given recent wide exposure of site questions in the hot list, with all assorted ["trails and tribulations"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217573/the-anatomy-of-a-hot-question "see: The Anatomy of a Hot Question"), post-graduation [decrements of community moderation privileges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67054/1657730) might turn out troublesome. Though, recent SE team [experiments with hot list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218248/165773) could make this less of a concern

Comment: @gnat Do you happen to know the average number of 10K users at graduation for recently-graduated sites? We're at ~15 which doesn't seem _too_ low, but I haven't looked closely at mapping the current users against future priv levels to see what we'd _really_ be in for...

Comment: @jcmeloni compared to _average_, our numbers probably look good-to-exceptional. :) Per my observations, process of _maturing_ of TWP core community was very stable and sane, organic. Having ~80 users with 2K edit privileges and ~50 with 3K to close/reopen also makes me feel we're doing great. It's only high exposure to hot list that somewhat worries me, otherwise I'd feel safe to claim we're 200% ready to graduate.

Comment: @Gnat - I think it can be offset by electing some active mods that will help keep the site clean.  We have a few users who do what they can but they lack the ability to deal with the exceptional issues.

Comment: @Chad agree that electing more mods would help... and that we have good candidates for elections. :) That's a very good point you made in the question: _"can we get an extra mod or 2 to help handle the volume that we have?"_

Comment: Yes, we are! http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2331/437

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just to clarify, yes, **The Workplace is graduating!**

The community team has been well aware of all the progress this site has made, and we decided it was time. Your new [site design](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/site-design-for-workplace-se) is in its final stages, thanks to [Stéphane](https://twitter.com/stephane_m_), the newest addition to the SE design team.

In a few weeks, the new brand new skin for The Workplace will go live. Until then, sit tight, and keep doing what you've been doing to make The Workplace great.

Comment: Great news Ana! Thanks (and welcome to the SE community team by the way). How many moderators will we have, and when will elections be?

Comment: Thank you @jmac! We typically elect three moderators, and you can expect to see the election take place a few weeks after the site design goes live.

Comment: Is that number negotiable? We have a very large volume of traffic for a beta site and post-graduation with the increase in reputation required for privileges, our community will lose a large amount of community moderation (especially for protection and closing of questions). Not saying we necessarily need more than 3, but it would be nice to know if we had the option if desired.

Comment: @jmac - Generally, most SE sites graduate with 3, and if there's a need for more, the community team either pulls the next runner up or holds another election. Additionally, we'll need to rely heavily on flagging until more people hit the privilege thresholds to vote to close, reopen, and delete.

Comment: @jmort, I think day-to-day should be fine. I am worried that when a hot question hits if our moderator is one of our high-rep users, the moderation burden will be a bit overwhelming. I would also anticipate that as soon as we graduate, we will get a lot more traffic all of a sudden which will likely tax our budding community moderation as an official site. I guess we'll see, but I'd love to start off on the right foot.

Answer (score 6):

It must be, otherwise why would they create this fantastic concept site for us!

[Site design for Workplace.se](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/site-design-for-workplace-se)

Anyone else feel like getting drunk and TPing Shog9's house?.... ohhh me neither :p

Comment: I'm totally for TPing Shog9's house.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

(simple answer, was just going to leave it at that but then decided I would expand..

It's active and I am finding it useful and have recently become one of your regular visitors. Obviously it's not as busy as some of the others, but it's getting there. I would say it should..)

Comment: Hi Marriott81! Welcome to Beta.Meta.Workplace.SE! Feel free to introduce yourself to the `core user base` in chat whenever you have a moment! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, however I am curious about the down vote from someone..

Comment: @JimG., if it's not open to public comment, like Marriott81's here, then it should be done through channels that don't allow for public comment.

Comment: Haha my bad, not that it was obvious who it was aimed at.. however I will now play Coy and wave a fan in front of myself to hide my embarrassment