# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design, graduation

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/site-design-for-workplace-se).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://cdn.sstatic.net/workplace/img/favicon.ico

http://cdn.sstatic.net/workplacemeta/img/favicon.ico

We have also themed the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), [twitter](https://twitter.com/StackWorkplace) account and [newsletter](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=workplace.stackexchange.com) template for this site.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Can't thank you enough for the fantastic design!

Comment: I love the design, however meta is excessively um... gray. By any chance could we get a bit more color here? :)

Comment: @Rachel yep, we'll be going over the main and meta sites for styling bugs and readability issues. But typically, Meta is always the gray, b/w version of the main site.

Comment: Links are really hard to differentiate from the surrounding text here on meta. I very nearly edited this post to hyperlink those images!

Comment: @Shog9 I already pushed a fix for that on dev.

Comment: Excellent, @Jin! And very nice work, Stephane!

Comment: @Jin Thanks :) It still looks good, but I think we're just missing a little gold or red or dull green that I see on most other meta sites.

Comment: @Rachel yeah because the link colors are wrong on meta right now. we'll fix it. I pushed a temp fix, but I'll let Stéphane decide on the final coloring tomorrow.

Comment: I LIKE IT!!! :D

Comment: gorgeous, I will be stoked for a while

Comment: Yayyy, something new for me to marvel at whilst I skive in work

Comment: It's amazing, well done :)

Comment: A thing of beauty!

Comment: There seems to be scope for some animation/transitioning on the Ask Question button ([gaming.se] has one too). When I mouseover the postit I sort of expect the turned up bit to either be pulled up completely or flattened down. Maybe it's just me, though :)

Comment: To add to Manishearth's point, I expect the "hit box" to be the whole post-it, not just the text.

Comment: Speaking of post-its, the tags somehow "stand out" now. Maybe they could be like post-its as well: smaller, rectangular and with a folded corner. But I'm not domestic at this site, so it's more a suggestion than a strong opinion. Anyways, I love the design, it's as messy on the page as on my table at work! :)

Comment: Good-looking design. It's curious, though, that all the theme elements seem to relate to office work (or work in general), none specifically to manual labor. Is the latter off-topic? I don't see anything about it at http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: This is, by far, the best design on SE in my opinion. Great job!