# When are Elections?

Tags: support, graduation, moderation, moderators, elections

We [graduated on February 20th](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/new-design-launched) which was two weeks ago. And that is awesome. But due to the loss of privilege, we are working the moderators to the bones with our flags and general cleanup.

While we all know that our moderators can clear Not An Answer flags with a single click, we may want to think about who will step into the Justice League in the future.

So when are we going to get around to this election thing?

Comment: ["We want you (to flush)!"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14143148#14143148)

Comment: I hope it is... ASAP. We need to bring the law upon our workplace. I mean, to bring order. Yes. But I do agree, I sense that we are getting a lot of work for the mod's.

Comment: @HugoRocha - Recommended reading for you and anyone considering a nomination:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: @jmort253 Done! Thanks for the link! :) I do agree with that, I see the point. We should leave the place more tidy then..

Comment: The recent Election on SO had a set of requirements to be nominated (certain badges and so on). Are there requirements to nominate here, too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We usually start looking into running elections about 30 days after a site graduates. Y'know, give it some nice foot room when they stew with their new design and privileges first, let people get comfortable and adjusted to the new reign. Exact dates may vary as we always start elections on Mondays and the graduation might not line up for precisely 30 days from that day to a Monday.

That puts us at about... March 24th as the Monday that it will most likely start.